# Null pointer assignment error in C, segmentation fault error in code

Tags: c

I using a old version of Borland for C lang.

At the beginning of the program you enter the name (full name, **FIO**), then 4 digits (as grades). The program calculates the average among 5 entered **FIO** and back a average number.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main(){
    struct nya{
        char a[100];
        int x[4];
    }A[5];
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<5;i++){
        puts("FIO");
        scanf("%s", A[i].a);
        puts("4 ocenki");
        for(int g=0;g<4;g++){
        scanf("%i", A[i].x[g]);
        }
    clrscr();
    }
    float bird=0, comme[5];
    for(i=0;i<5;i++){
        comme[i]=0;

    }
    for(i=0;i<5;i++){
        for(int g=0;g<4;g++){
            comme[i]+=A[i].x[g];
        }
        comme[i]=comme[i]/4;
        bird+=comme[i];
    }
    bird=bird/5;
    printf("Sredny = %f", bird);

}
```

Comment: change `scanf("%i", A[i].x[g]);` to `scanf("%i", &A[i].x[g]);` (with a `&`). You need to give `scanf` the address of where it should put the value that it reads.

Comment: Someone should write a bot which will scan question before posting for scanf errors and show @Blaze's comment as a pop-up!

Comment: @Swanand sometimes I think about feeding common questions like that into a neural network that can learn the most common errors and "guess" the solutions for new questions and show them as a hint. Or perhaps some kind of static code analysis, like a compiler that would emit a warning for such code.

Comment: @Swanand been thinking about it

Answer (score 0):

change `scanf("%i", A[i].x[g]);` to `scanf("%i", &A[i].x[g]);` (with a &)

thanks to @Blaze

Comment: If it is the correct answer, you should accept your own answer.